# Regex for three different enclosed text formats

Tags: regex

Given the following three strings of text:

```
export DB_USER='aodhfoi2'
export DB_USER = aodhfoi2
export DB_USER="aodhfoi2"
```

Without the single or double quotes, the regex would be:

```
^export (?<key>[^= ]+)\s*=\s*(?<value>.+)$
```

What would be the correct regex with the enclosing quotes? I assume I would need a conditional to make sure that if it starts with a `'` it ends with a `'` and not a `"`.

Current regex here: https://regex101.com/r/yqvUIX/3

Comment: do you want to match the middle one too (the one without quotes)?

Comment: @Bohemian yes, all three of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the value between the quotes as a separate value you could use another capturing group to capture an optional `"` or `'` with a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to what is captured in the group to match the quotes.

```
^export (?<key>[^= ]+)\s*=\s*(['"]?)(?<value>\S+)\2
```

Explanation of the last part

- `(['"]?)` Capture group 2, match optional `'` or `"`
- `(?<value>\S+)` Named group `value`, match 1+ times a non whitespace char
- `\2` Backreference to what is captured in group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kxz9my/1)

Comment: thanks, yes that was what I was looking for. Great answer.

Comment: Damn, The fourth bird was faster :) I had prepared example with named groups: `^export (?<key>[^= ]+)\s*=\s*(?<quote>['"]?)(?<value>.+)(?P=quote)$`

Comment: I wouldn't use `\S+` since it doesn't match strings with spaces (which is why quotes are usually used). So  original `.+` would fit better here.

Comment: @CraZ Yes, or perhaps in that case make the match a bit more restrictive using a negated character class if `'` and `"` can on occur at the beginning or end `^export (?<key>[^= ]+)\s*=\s*(['"]?)(?<value>[^"'\r\n]+)\2$` https://regex101.com/r/TBK1E4/1/